# XCode Version 8.3.1 (8E1000a) IBOutlet Connect Issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]

In the image see the highlighted portion .swift(Interface), When I get this it makes me unable to drag and connect from storyboard to viewcontroller class.

I have searched but not getting any clue that what is the issue behind this.

Can anyone help regarding this?

I have tried, clearing cache, cleaning the build, restarting the MBP etc but nothing helped.

I am unable to solve it out.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. The word "automatic" helped me resolving this issue. I just selected the storyboard and then selected the Automatic on the other side and then got the required list. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than choosing "manual" and selecting the interface, you might use "automatic" and when you select the control in IB, you should see the actual .swift file (not the interface) in the assistant editor, and you should be able to control-drag at that point.

And you didn't mention it, but if you ever have troubles hooking up outlets, double check that the base class has been properly set in IB before you try hooking up outlets.

Comment: Thanks @Rob your answer helped me

Answer (score 0):

This is a Xcode bug, update to 8.3.2 to see if it fixes your problem (it doesn't show up on the app store update sometimes, so manually download it)

Comment: ThiagoAM, can't say if it is a bug, but have resolved the issue with few clicks.